# How do I replace ugly "PC" font in Linux boot CLI?

Tags: boot, virtualbox, fonts

When I boot Linux in VirtualBox, it comes up with a bold font which seems to be the same as old DOS/IBM machines and even OS X single user mode. I'd like to know more about this font:

1. What's it called, who created it and when?
2. Why is it still being used after all these years?
3. Is it embedded into the Linux core, or is it part of the VirtualBox emulation?
4. How can I replace it with a font of my choice?

Answer (score 2):

VirtualBox uses the plex86 VGAbios. From the [README](https://www.virtualbox.org/svn/vbox/trunk/src/VBox/Devices/Graphics/BIOS/README):

```
The source code contains fonts from fntcol16.zip (c) by Joseph Gil avalable at :
ftp://ftp.simtel.net/pub/simtelnet/msdos/screen/fntcol16.zip
These fonts are public domain
```

So this is part of the emulation.

Looking through the output of `dpkg -L virtualbox-5.0` doesn't give an clear candidate file that might contain the fonts, so maybe they are compiled in.